# MySQL CHAR data type

Tags: mysql, char

W3Schools says it must that it is a fixed-length(n). Does that mean it must be that length? But in MySQL I can enter 6 characters and it will accept it.

Please explain. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

char data type is fixed length. it means whichever value you gonna give it will convert it to that specific length. for example you declared a column char(10).

if you insert a 'abcd' in that column, it will stored as 'abcd' + 6 extra space right padded with it.

if you give '123456789012', it will truncate last two charecter and store '1234567890'.